# Bending moment capacity of T-cross-section (reinforced concrete)

Tags: structural-engineering, reinforced-concrete, bending

I have a question regarding a simplification/derivation of the (ULS) bending moment **capacity of a *given*** T-cross-section, with compression-zone on the flanged side. **The problem is that the rebar-strain $\varepsilon_s$ (here) reaches $\varepsilon_{ud}$ (which cannot be exceeded) before the concrete strain $\varepsilon_c = \varepsilon_{cu}$. This means that a rectangular stress block approximation cannot be used (ref. Eurocode 2, point 3.1.7(2))**

[image: ![enter image description here]

The simplification is from a Norwegian book, hence I can't upload the relevant pages. The translation reads approximately:

*Usually, the flange is so large that the compression zone (heightwise) is small. This leads to a large rebar strain $\varepsilon_s$ before the ultimate compressive strain $\varepsilon_{cu}$ is reached.*

*If $\varepsilon_s$ reaches $\varepsilon_{ud}$* [ultimate rebar-strain] *before $\varepsilon_{c}$ reaches $\varepsilon_{cu}$* [the rebar fractures before the concrete] *one usually assumes constant compressive concrete stress acting **only** in the flange, such that the concrete force resultant acts in the middle of the flange*.

*Moment equilibrium (rebar force) about the flange's middle yields design moment resistance $M_{Rd}$*

$$M_{Rd}=f_{yd}\cdot A_s \cdot \Big(d-\frac{t}{2}\Big),$$

*where $f_{yd}$ is rebar design yield stress.*

*One must check with this assumption, that the stress in the flange does not exceed the design concrete compressive stress $f_{cd}$.*

*Since flange moment capacity is assumed to be*

$$M_{Rd}=\sigma_{cd}\cdot b_{eff}\cdot t\cdot \Big(d-\frac{t}{2}\Big),$$

*we must have*

$$\sigma_{cd}=\frac{M_{Rd}}{t\cdot b_{eff}\Big(d-\frac{t}{2}\Big)}\leq f_{cd}$$

*If this is the case, the capacity-estimate is conservative.*

So the 'math' is clear, but I can't see the justification behind the assumption. Has the author used the lower bound theorem (theory of plasticity), or is there anything else I can't spot?

Thanks

Comment: It's an interesting question. But could you define the terms that appear in the equations and figures? I didn't understand a few of them.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with you.

we should establish the neutral axis and apply the $\varepsilon_{cu} \ ,$ The you find out the $\varepsilon_s \ ,$
And these are your strains. and the stress, S, of  the steel bars is just $S_{steel}= E_{steel}*\varepsilon_s $

From here you proceed as normal and calculate the C=T and the moment arm d